# Does `throw` refund the ether value?

Tags: solidity, transactions, exceptions

When a contract triggers a `throw`, the Solidity document states:

> Solidity will trigger an "invalid jump" and thus cause the EVM to revert all changes made to the state.

In this case, what happens to the ether value (not the gas) that was sent along with the transaction? Is it returned to the sender, or is it still stored in the contract?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ether value that was sent along with the transaction (or call if the exception is caught) is returned to the sender if you use `throw` in Solidity.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, all funds are returned to the sender, except the gas. https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#throw