# Throw vs. Return

Tags: solidity, contract-design, dapp-development, contract-debugging, exceptions

We're trying to figure out whether to use `return` or `throw` in Solidity when a condition fails and we don't assume user maliciousness. Here's the pros and cons we've figured so far:

#### Why use `throw`

- Any side effects of the code are reverted
- Some wallets may predict `throw` ahead of time, warning the user

#### Why use `return`

- Less gas is consumed by the unsuspecting user (again, assuming not a malicious call).
- A calling contract may gracefully recover from the failure, unlike with `throw`.

Are there any other considerations (or best-practices) we should be aware of?

Answer (score 10):

All the considerations in the question are helpful.

`throw` is safer since it ensures that there are no side effects that remain, but another consideration is error reporting.  With `throw` there's currently [no way to get more information about the error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4085/is-it-a-good-practice-to-log-an-event-every-time-i-throw-in-solidity) whereas Events and error codes could be used with `return` to convey a more granular reason about the error.

Another thing to be aware of when using web3.js, is that when a Solidity `throw` is encountered, *currently* [web3.js has an issue with `false` values](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/364).

EDIT:  Since `throw` consumes all gas, keep an eye on [EIP 140 REVERT instruction](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/206/files):

> The `REVERT` instruction provides a way to stop execution and revert
>   state changes, without consuming all provided gas and with the ability
>   to return a reason.

Comment: Be careful because throw doesn't return the sent ether, it only rollbacks changes to data.

Comment: @PabloYabo Correct if you meant that `throw` consumes all gas and I added the clarification.  Otherwise, an ether transfer is reverted with either a `throw` or `revert`.

Comment: What I mean is that if you call send function to send Ether to another account, it doesn't rollback the sent ether with a throw.

Comment: @PabloYabo A `throw` does rollback the sent ether: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2428/does-throw-refund-the-ether-value

Comment: the throw returns sent ether but it doesn't rollback ether sent within the executed code. It returns the msg.value but only that. If you sent ether in your code, it isn't rolled back.

Comment: Hi @PabloYabo Can you please open a new question for what you're observing? A transaction that throws will consume all gas and all state changes and ether transfers are rolled back.

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to consider why *not* to use throw / return:

**Why not use throw**

- All gas is consumed, everything reverted
- Impossible to tell callers why the call failed
- Errors cannot be caught, so they cannot be handled gracefully

**Why not use return**

- It may not be clear to callers that the function can unsuccessfully run.  This can lead to disastrous consequences:  `contract.doSomeImportantCall()` may return `false`, but the caller instead expected a throw, so unless they check the return value bad things can happen.
- You will find yourself returning multiple values everywhere: eg `returns (bool _successful, uint _result)` vs `returns (uint _result)`
- Handling multiple return values is cumbersome and more difficult to test against.

There really is no consensus on the proper way to do things.  In fact, there is currently a debate over throw vs return for `transfer` on the updated ERC20 spec, for example.