# Exact behavior of state revert in `try/catch`

Tags: solidity, try-catch

I'm trying to make sure I fully understand the behavior of `try/catch`, specifically what state gets reverted when we catch an error. I could not be sure of certain behavior from [the v0.8.10 docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/control-structures.html). If I have code like:

```
otherContract.firstMethod()
try otherContract.secondMethod{value: 10, gas: 1000}() {}
catch (bytes memory) {
    // some code
}
```

Let's say that `otherContract.firstMethod` and `otherContract.secondMethod` both modify state within `otherContract`. If we end up in the catch block, am I correct in the following statements:

1. the state changes in `otherContract` made by `otherContract.firstMethod` will **not** be reverted
2. the state changes in `otherContract` made by `otherContract.secondMethod` will be reverted

From [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2428/does-throw-refund-the-ether-value) it appears that the 10 sent to `otherContract` will be refunded but any used gas will not be refunded.

Are all of the above correct? Anything incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The try/catch in solidity only check for reverts in call to another contracts.

It doesn't revert state changes by itself. It only allows the caller to detect a revert in the callee.

It is easy to test with a contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract A {
    uint public a;

    constructor(uint x) {
        a = x;
    }

    function foo(uint y) public {
        a = y;
    }
}

contract B {
    A public a;

    event Result(uint);

    constructor() {
        // a.a initial value is 1
        a = new A(1);
    }

    function bar() public {
        // sets a.a = 123
        a.foo(123);

        // if successful it will set a.a = 1111
        // call will revert due to out of gas
        try a.foo{gas: 1000}(1111) {
            // This will never be execute due to the revert
            emit Result(8989);
        } catch (bytes memory) {
            // We do nothing in case of revert
        }

        // Read a.a
        uint r = a.a();

        // Emit obtained value (it should be 123)
        emit Result(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: So if state changes occur in the called function, in this case `a.foo{gas: 1000}(1111)`, if `a.foo` reverts, the state changes that occur within the call to `a.foo` revert. I just tried that  without the gas limit to make sure that the state changes were hit, and the above is correct. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if the catch is entered, any state change before "try" is kept, as well as anything in the catch. If there is a REVERT within the try block, the entire tx REVERTs (the "try" only applies to the external CALL or contract creation)